# Crear objetos dentro o fuera de bucle iterativo en C++

Tags: c++, objeto, iteradores, serialport

Estoy utilizando un objeto para hacer lecturas del puerto serie ([CppLinuxSerial](https://github.com/gbmhunter/CppLinuxSerial)). Creo  el objeto y después leo el puerto serie y trato el mensaje dentro de un while infinito.
¿Es mejor crear los objetos dentro del while e ir destruyéndolos para tratar cada mensaje como objetos distintos o mejor tener un único objeto e irlo modificando?

Es decir, ¿mejora en algo esto...

```
#include "CppLinuxSerial/SerialPort.hpp"
#include "Mensaje.h"

using namespace mn::CppLinuxSerial;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Creación y configuración (8N1) del objeto
    SerialPort *serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyS0", BaudRate::B_115200, NumDataBits::EIGHT, Parity::NONE, NumStopBits::ONE);

    serialPort->SetTimeout(-1); // -1: Bloquea hasta recibir algún dato. Entre paréntesis ms

    vector<uint8_t> msgVector;

    // Lectura de datos binarios
    int descartados = 0; /** @todo Agregar descartes al log*/

    while (serialPort.available())
    {
        cout << "\n            Inicio del tratamiento";
        cout << "\n*********************************************\n\n";

        msgVector.clear();

        serialPort->Open();
        serialPort->ReadBinary(msgVector);
        serialPort->Close();

        Mensaje msg;  // De esta forma creo un objeto en cada iteración

        if (msg.definicion(msgVector)){
            cout << "\nDefiniendo datos...\n";
        }
        else
            descartados++;

        cout << "\n\nMensajes descartados: " << descartados << endl;

        msg.~Mensaje();
    }
    // if(serialPort.GetState()==State::OPEN)
    serialPort->Close();
}
```

...a esto:

```
#include "CppLinuxSerial/SerialPort.hpp"
#include "Mensaje.h"

using namespace mn::CppLinuxSerial;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<uint8_t> msgVector;
    
    // Lectura de datos binarios
    int descartados = 0; /** @todo Agregar descartes al log*/

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "\n            Inicio del tratamiento";
        cout << "\n*********************************************\n\n";
        // Creación y configuración (8N1) del objeto
        SerialPort serialPort("/dev/ttyS0", BaudRate::B_115200, NumDataBits::EIGHT, Parity::NONE, NumStopBits::ONE);
        serialPort.SetTimeout(-1); 

        msgVector.clear();

        serialPort.Open();
        serialPort.ReadBinary(msgVector);
        serialPort.Close();

        Mensaje msg;

        if (msg.definicion(msgVector)){
            cout << "\nDefiniendo datos...\n";
        }
        else
            descartados++;

        cout << "\n\nMensajes descartados: " << descartados << endl;

        msg.~Mensaje();
        serialPort.~SerialPort();
    }
}
```

No sé si crear tantos objetos ocupa memoria y puede darme problemas en un futuro o si ir modificando el contenido de un solo objeto puede causarme problemas por corrupción de datos.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Define "*mejor*".

Comment: Mejor en cualquier sentido, quiero decir, consume menos memoria, menos posibilidades de fallo... Cualquier diferencia de un modo respecto del otro. ¡Gracias,  
PaperBirdMaster!

Comment: Sin saber cómo es el objeto ni cómo lo usas y con una definición tan vaga de "*mejor*", la respuesta variará entre "no tengo ni idea" y "podría poder ser posible que no lo supiera". Comparte algo de código para que podamos analizarlo.

Comment: Respuesta corta: no te preocupes demasiado. Solo manten tu lógica simple y el compilador se encargará de optimizar el programa.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes analizar el código generado por tu compilador usando [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/). Según tu descripción tienes un bucle infinito y un objeto creado dentro del bucle:

```
struct S
{
};

void f()
{
    while (true)
    {
        S s;
    }
}
```

Esto genera muy poco código ASM:

```
f():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
.L2:
        jmp     .L2
```

Pero claro, el objeto no hace nada; si le añadimos una función:

```
struct S
{
    void f() {}
};

void f()
{
    while (true)
    {
        S s;
        s.f();
    }
}
```

Vemos que en el ASM se añaden unas líneas para hacer la función y su llamada:

```
S::f():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
f():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
.L3:
        lea     rax, [rbp-1]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    S::f()
        jmp     .L3
```

Pero claro, el objeto es trivial (no tiene constructor ni destructor), si se los añadimos:

```
struct S
{
    S(){}
    ~S(){}
    void f() {}
};

void f()
{
    while (true)
    {
        S s;
        s.f();
    }
}
```

Vemos que el ASM genera esas funciones y las llama en cada vuelta del bucle:

```
S::S() [base object constructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
S::~S() [base object destructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
S::f():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
f():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
.L5:
        lea     rax, [rbp-1]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    S::S() [complete object constructor]
        lea     rax, [rbp-1]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    S::f()
        lea     rax, [rbp-1]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    S::~S() [complete object destructor]
        jmp     .L5
```

Pero claro, estamos compilando sin optimizaciones de compilador, si añadimos la máxima optimización...

```
f():
.L2:
        jmp     .L2
```

...  obtenemos sólo el bucle, porque el objeto no hace nada. Lo cuál me lleva a:

- Si no sabemos cómo es tu programa.
- Si no sabemos cómo es tu objeto.
- Si no sabemos cómo estás compilando.
- Si no sabemos lo que significa "*mejor*" en tu contexto.

No sabremos cómo responder tu duda.